# How to copy the geometry WKT from a temporary scratch layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, well-known-text

It seems in the 2.14.2 version of QGIS the ability to copy the WKT from the geometry of a temporary scratch layer has been removed.

Previously you could create, for example, a new polygon feature in a temporary scratch layer and use the identify tool to reveal the attributes of the temporary feature. From there, you could right-click the feature and 'copy' the feature attributes, which contained the WKT of the geometry of the feature.

Now the identify window and the attribute table are both blank where they used to show the attributes of the feature.

That was super handy for spatial queries using ad-hoc geometries...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just select the feature and CTRL-C copy it from the main map canvas. If that doesn't include the WKT, check under Options -> Data Sources and make sure "Copy geometry in WKT representation..." is checked.

Comment: Oh! There it is! Funny how the Identify window and attribute table don't show this anymore, but glad to know it's still there! Thank you!!!